# Is Actionable Messages / Adaptive Cards supported in Exchange 2016 Hybrid environment?

Tags: adaptive-cards, actionable-notification

Is Actionable Messages / Adaptive Cards supported in Exchange 2016 Hybrid environment?

I registered the connector provider in the Outlook Online Dev Playground. Ensured all of my adaptive cards had the correct originator ids. Waiting beyond the 24 hours. Yet, all messages are still coming across empty